# Can't add new language to a Drupal 8 installation

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have installed a Drupal 8 installation using the app utility from my hosting.

The main language is Spanish, but when I'm trying to add two new languages from admin/config/regional/language there is no "Add language" button. The module Interface Translation is installed.

Is it possible that languages are locked by any configuration file? How can I make the button appear again?

Answer (score 0):

Uff, silly me!!! The problem was that the block that shows the link to add a new language was removed from my admin theme. Ok, I hope this helps somebody else with a similar problem too.